Alternatives to the method of stationary phase
The stationary phase method deals with integrals such as $$I=\int_a^bf(t)e^{i\lambda g(t)}dt,$$ where $\lambda\gg1$ is a large parameter.
The method of stationary phase tells us that if there is a stationary point $c\in (a,b)$ with $g''(c)\ne 0$ then we can say that the above integral is approximately $$I\sim f(c)e^{i\lambda g(c)}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\lambda|g''(c)|}}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$$ as $\lambda\to\infty$. I am interested in the following variant:

Can we estimate the integral $$I_1=\int_a^bf(t)e^{g(t)}dt$$ where $\lambda=1$ and the stationary point $c\in (a,b)$ is such that $g''(c)$ is nonzero but tiny?

There are two significant differences between this integral and the type usually dealt with via stationary phase. Firstly, the 'large' parameter is actually $1$, and this will affect the accuracy of the approximation. Secondly, $g''(c)$ being close to zero will give us an integral that is massive (and I expect too far from the true value). Are there any similar methods that account for these constraints?

you might as well have $g(t)\equiv 0$, and ask for a "method" to estimate $\int_a^b f(t),dt$; without further info on $f$ this question has no useful answer.
